# Sed to copy part of file name into another contents of file with same substring

Tags: shell-script, files, sed

For every file with the specified extension within one directory, I would like to use just a substring from the filename to add to another file and output as a file with a different extension but the same substring.

I have found some similar examples to what I would like to do but I am writing a bash script so I have run into some challenges I have had a hard time finding examples of.

For example, I would start with filename.sample and I only want the substring "filename".

What I tried to do is:

```
for i in /path/to/*.sample
do
   bar="${i%%.sample*}"
   sed "s/^>\(.*\)/>\1;label=${bar##*/};/" "$i" > "$i"_bar  \;
done
```

The contents of `*.sample` files are as follows:

```
*.sample

> MEWFJWRNFF_141
AB28974UJBDASX
```

The desired output is:

```
Output_bar
> MEWFJWRNFF_141; label=filename;
AB28974UJBDASX
```

Let me know if I have been unclear in any way! Thank you!

Comment: The unnecessary `\;` at the end of the `sed` command makes it choke looking for a file called `;` I think

Comment: though that shouldn't stop sed from processing the first file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i in /path/to/*.sample
do
    str="; label=$(basename -s.sample $i);"
    sed "/^>/ s/$/$str/" "$i"
done
```

- `basename` command gives only the name of file, stripping away path. And `-s.sample` will strip the extension
- So, if `i` is `/path/to/filename.sample` , `str` will contain `; label=filename;`
- `/^>/ s/$/$str/` will find a line starting with `>` and add the contents of `str` variable to end of that line

---

I do not get how you want the output file to be named. If `i` is `/path/to/filename.sample`, `"$i"_bar` will give `/path/to/filename.sample_bar`

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! You are correct, what I wrote here for the output is not exactly ideal so I set the output file to "${i%%.sample*}"_bar and the output is perfect. :)